# Linebreaks gets converted to spaces when different font is used

Tags: java

I'm trying to make my lines break every 20 characters, which i am using this code for:

```
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Character> keyWithLetter : keyMap.entrySet()) {
        if (input.isKeyPressed(keyWithLetter.getKey())) {
            String charCount = this.tekst.replaceAll("\\n", "");
            if (charCount.length() % 20 == 0 && charCount.length() >= 20) {
                this.tekst += "\n";
            }
            this.tekst += keyWithLetter.getValue();
        }
    }
```

It works fine with the standard font. However, when i change the font to Verdana, the linebreaks gets converted to spaces instead. What causes this?

Here's the font:

```
    Font awtFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 13);
    this.font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, true);
```

Comment: seems strange, can you provide sample working code with this problem to test?

Comment: Is it just Verdana or is it every other font?

Comment: Where and how are you printing the output? Do you realise that on for example a HTML page, line breaks in the HTML code do not mean line breaks on screen in the browser?

Comment: I was printing it on a Graphics screen. However, i just figured it's the framework i'm using that messes it up. Sorry for the inconvenience :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework i was using, Slick2d, have a TrueTypeFont class which doesn't support the \n linebreak.